# For a data frame with similar and dissimilar numerical values, how do I keep values that for instance are further apart than plus or minus 0.05?

Tags: r, for-loop, filtering, conditional-statements

I had to analyze data in separate experiments so I fear that some of the rows in my data frame are the same feature even though the m/z median value is slightly different. I want to be able to put a plus or minus 0.05 condition to the m/z median values and keep only the first instance this occurs.

The data provided has `x` as the index number, the name that the `xcms` package gives to each feature based on mass to charge and retention time, the m/z median value which I plan to filter around (`mzmed`), and retention times in minutes.

`length(unique(All_Isocratic$ordered_reporttab.name))` is not sufficient since the mass and time are rounded to whole integer values (M 293, T 51 seconds).
I think a for loop may work, but I'm struggling with how to keep the entire data frame for those mzmed values that satisfy the condition of being unique to within plus or minus 0.05 of the other values.

```
head(All_Isocratic, n = 10) 
    [X]         [ordered_reporttab.name]
1  1712                M293T51
2  2384                M315T44
3  1689                M160T52
4  1365                M169T50
5  1355                M204T44
6   971                 M69T35
7  1483               M293T52
8  1622                M130T53
9  2307                M199T34
10 1753               M293T51
       [mzmed] [Retention_Times]
1  293.08677       0.8481379
2  315.00825       0.7343729
3  160.06174       0.8743856
4  169.06872       0.8410968
5  204.06996       0.7400242
6   68.98316       0.5831329
7  293.10242       0.8522436
8  130.06592       0.8852018
9  198.94047       0.5662835
10 293.06542       0.8421682
```

My expected output would look something like this:
I would not expect row 7 and 10 to survive the filtering process.

```
head(All_Isocratic, n = 8) 
    [X]         [ordered_reporttab.name]
1  1712                M293T51
2  2384                M315T44
3  1689                M160T52
4  1365                M169T50
5  1355                M204T44
6   971                 M69T35
7  1622                M130T53
8  2307                M199T34
       [mzmed] [Retention_Times]
1  293.08677       0.8481379
2  315.00825       0.7343729
3  160.06174       0.8743856
4  169.06872       0.8410968
5  204.06996       0.7400242
6   68.98316       0.5831329
7  130.06592       0.8852018
8  198.94047       0.5662835
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider using `dplyr`. Since you are looking to eliminate those within 0.05 of the `mzmed` I would `arrange` it first then check:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
arrange(mzmed) %>%
mutate(check = if_else(abs(lag(mzmed, default = 0) - mzmed)) <= 0.05, 1, 0)) %>%
filter(check != 1)
```

Not sure if order matters (like keeping the largest `mzmed` or smallest `mzmed` value). If it doesn't this will work, otherwise you may have to also create another way to `arrange` the data.

Answer (score 1):

You could just round until the first decimal, which satisfies your condition. Your code would simply be

```
answer = All_Isocratic[!duplicated(round(All_Isocratic$mzmed,1)),]
```

**edit**

Hopefully if your data is not too big you can get away with this loop

```
mzmed = All_Isocratics$mzmed
trues = rep(TRUE,length(mzmed))            # vector of logical, all TRUE
for (i in 1:length(mzmed)){                # loop through nrow of dataframe
  if (trues[i]){                           # if value has not been discarded, use as reference
      el = which(abs(mzmed[i]-mzmed)<0.05) # which values are in a +-0.05 range from reference
      trues[el[el!=i]]=FALSE               # turn values in range (except for the reference itself) to FALSE
  }
}
result = All_Isocratics[trues,]
```

Comment: Thank you boski. I am worried about losing precision though with rounding. My mzmed values will not necessarily round to the same values either such that I can consistently remove them (a feature at 293.04 may be close enough to the 293.08677 such that it is the same feature, but this would round down now)

Comment: You are absolutely right. This yields another question; what if you had this sequence: `c(0,0.4,0.9,1.4,1.9,2.4 ...)` would this be a single sample? There is a 2.4 gap from first to last, but the steps between each are 0.5 ...

Comment: Good question and example. With the instrument I used to collect mzmed, there is a standard error of plus or minus 0.05. It's true that I may end up eliminating some different features that are within that range, but I'm more worried about counting the same feature more than once for my analysis.

Comment: Hi Boski, I'm looking back through this example for a similar issue that I'm facing and was curious as to how I may be able to implement the for loop you mentioned above to work for both mzmed and Retention_Times. Basically I want to be able to put in some sort of threshold for both variables and keep only the "unique pairs" (within some set threshold like 0.05 for mzmed and 0.001 for Retention_Times). So if something has the same or similar mzmed but very different Retention_Time I would like to keep both insances, does that make sense?